# First time owner dealing with parasites in stool

Tags: dogs, parasites

I am a first time owner of a puppy.
I have recently taken him to the vet and today the vet called telling me he has a parasite in his poo. The vet told me that he is going to give him a powder. I was wondering if there something else I should be doing. He is currently being trained to poo in one spot (not working so far since he does it everywhere). There are also two kids in the house and they play on the carpet and floor where the dog sometimes poos. I was wondering does the parasite spread? 
Any advice would be really appreciated.

Comment: you need to ask your vet about what type of parasites it is,some of them can infect people but your vet will tell you this and  what you need to do.

Comment: Making sure to wash the dog's bedding frequently is helpful for general hygiene and parasite control, but your questions depend on exactly what the parasite is.

Comment: Thank you so much for the comments. I have contacted my vet and I was told that it is only transmittable if you eat the stool. Also, I had no idea about the bedding I will get to it!!!